# How do I destroy a aws SAM Local lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-sam-cli

Follow the read for an example it says:

```
# AWS SAM Hello World Example #

A simple AWS SAM template that specifies a single Lambda function.

## Usage ##

To create and deploy the SAM Hello World example, first ensure that you've met the requirements described in the [root README](../../README.md). Then
follow the steps below.

### Test your application locally ###

Use [SAM Local](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-local) to run your Lambda function locally:

    sam local invoke "HelloWorldFunction" -e event.json

### Package artifacts ###

Run the following command, replacing `BUCKET-NAME` with the name of your bucket:

    sam package --template-file template.yaml --s3-bucket BUCKET-NAME --output-template-file packaged-template.yaml

This creates a new template file, packaged-template.yaml, that you will use to deploy your serverless application.

### Deploy to AWS CloudFormation ###

Run the following command, replacing `MY-NEW-STACK` with a name for your CloudFormation stack.

    sam deploy --template-file packaged-template.yaml --stack-name MY-NEW-STACK --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM

This uploads your template to an S3 bucket and deploys the specified resources using AWS CloudFormation.
```

Now what is the sam local command to delete the whole stack including s3 bucket and CF stack?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Edit for 2022:

Sam cli now has a `delete` command can see official docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-delete.html). Should be able run like this now:

`sam delete --stack-name MY-NEW-STACK`

Thanks @jesusnoseq for pointer to update .

---

Legacy 2018 Answer

There is currently no sam command to delete all of these resources. You would just use the relevant aws cli commands which sam-cli is just a wrapper around anyways. Example to delete you CFN stack.

`aws cloudformation delete-stack --stack-name MY-NEW-STACK`

Comment: You can also just go to Cloudformation from the AWS Console, and delete the stack if you forget the name.

Comment: want to add that "sam deploy" is useless. Its a wrapper around "aws cloudformation deploy" that does the same thing and actually has _less_ feature. Sam deploy doesn't have a region switch

Comment: want to add the sam itself is pretty useless and a bad copy of sls :/ . Sorry for that

Comment: `sam deploy` not `sam invoke` and it _was_ useless back when it was just a very wonky wrapper around cloudformation commands (2 years ago). this is no longer the case as the current sam build/package/deploy workflow solved most  problems but you still have to use a different command (cloudformation) to cleanup/destroy a sam app which is a slight inconvenience

Comment: Now there is a `sam delete` command. 
 [Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-delete.html)